# Why backdropClass does not work in mat-paginator?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular7

When I add the property backdropClass to mat-paginator does not apply to the cdk-overlay-container  to modify the pop up window that shows the option for the page size.

[image: The current behaviour]

```
<mat-paginator
          backdropClass="yellow"
          [pageSize]="20"
          [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 100]"
        ></mat-paginator>
```

The expected result should be somenthing like this:

```
<div class="cdk-overlay-backdrop yellow cdk-overlay-backdrop-showing"></div>
```

but instead the result is this one:

[image: The current behaviour]

In order to modify just only that "page size popUp window" with the class `yellow` but unfortunately it does not work and all the select inputs windows are changed by the css added here.

```
::ng-deep{
  .ng-trigger-transformPanel{
    transform: translateY(-142px) scaleY(1) !important;
  }
}
```

affecting other components:

[image: The current behaviour]

So it's necessary to have the yellow class to be able to differentiate the other components and use correct Css.

```
  .yellow {
    .ng-trigger-transformPanel{
      transform: translateY(-142px) scaleY(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The mat-paginator doesn't have an input property called ```backdropClass```. It has to be used with the selector ```cdk-connected-overlay```. Can you add the code surrounding the mat-paginator element?

Comment: [The code sorrounding the mat-paginator](https://i.imgur.com/K71pizo.png)

Comment: I guess I'm still confused about what you're trying to accomplish. MatPaginator doesn't have an input property called backdropClass, so adding it inside the mat-paginator just won't work. But in the code you linked to, you don't have backdropClass inside the mat-paginator, so maybe I'm missing something? Where does the overlay come in?

Comment: Yes indeed you are right in the code is not added, Sorry. My question is how I can modify the css of the class `ng-trigger-transformPanel` that is inside the `cdk` classes without changing all the `ng-trigger-transformPanel` in other components